# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar un helper usando la convención de Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo los modelos Color, Casa, Urbanismno y Ciudad, donde el modelo Color pertenece al modelo Casa, el modelo Casa pertenece al modelo Urbanismo y el modelo Urbanismo pertenece al modelo Ciudad.

Aquí están los códigos parciales de los modelos involucrados:

**Modelo Color**

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :casa

  def ciudad_id
    casa.urbanismo.ciudad_id
  end

end
```

**Modelo Casa**

```
class Casa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :urbanismo
end
```

**Modelo Urbanismo**

```
class Urbanismo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ciudad
end
```

Quiero saber todas las casas de cierto color en cierta ciudad, por ejemplo,
quiero saber la cantidad de casas de color azul en la ciudad con id = 1

En el controlador llamo a un método con un parámetro:

```
nombre_de_color = 'azul'
ciudad_id = 1
casas_de_color(nombre_de_color, ciudad_id)
```

En un helper tengo estas dos propuestas:

**Propuesta 1:**

```
def casas_de_color(nombre_de_color, ciudad_id)
    contador = 0
    Color.where(nombre: nombre_de_color).each do |color|
      contador += 1 if color.casa.urbanismo.ciudad_id == ciudad_id
    end
    contador
end
```

Si creo el atributo ciudad_id dentro del modelo Color, como se ve mas arriba puedo hacer la siguiente consulta, pero es practicamente igual a la anterior.

**Propuesta 2:**

```
def casas_de_color(nombre_de_color, ciudad_id)
    contador = 0
    Color.where(nombre: nombre_de_color).each do |color|
      contador += 1 if color.ciudad_id == ciudad_id
    end
    contador
end
```

*¿Cómo puedo mejorar estas propuestas en un helper usando la convención de Ruby?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es un problema de convención de Ruby, sino de traer toda la info necesaria desde la BD en una misma consulta sin tener que iterar sobre cada elemento. Primera cosa, sería agregar en `Casa` la relación que tiene con `Color`.

```
class Casa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :urbanismo
  has_one :color # o has_many, ahí tu sabes
end
```

luego creo que la consulta principal debería ser sobre el modelo `Casa` porque quieres saber cuántas casas son de cierto color en cierta ciudad, cierto?

```
Casa.joins(:colors, :urbanismo).where(
  urbanismos: { ciudad_id: ciudad_id }, colors: { nombre: nombre_de_color }
).count
```

Eso debería retornarte la cuenta total.